# Are Chrome extensions slowing down my browser and how do I fix this without deleting them?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I checked Task Manager and discovered what you see in the picture. Is this slowing my browser down and can it be fixed without deleting my extensions? I only have a few including Adblock Plus, Adblock, uBlock and they never showed up in Task Manager like this in Firefox.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"Are Chrome extension slowing down my browser?" Yes.

"How do I fix this without deleting them?" You don't.

Extensions always have some impact. Whether that impact is acceptable or not is up to you to decide.

Outside of adjusting a particular extension's settings, there isn't really a way to reduce their impact.

Chrome splits individual tabs and other tasks into separate processes. This is why you see so many entries. Chrome doesn't necessarily use more or less memory or processing power than Firefox because of this.

Note that Firefox is soon moving to this model as well.